# "move back the appointment two days" or "move back the oppointment by two days"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me If I have to include the proposition *by* in the following sentence?

> Is it possible to move back the dentist appointment (**by**) two days?

Comment: This is an editing question. But we say: move up, not move back.

Comment: I should have said **to bring it forward by 2 days** if you want an earlier appointment or **to make it 2 days later** if you want a later one.

Comment: Even native speakers find phrases like "move up" or "push back" to be [confusing and ambiguous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/scheduling-woes-and-the-ambiguous-adverbs-that-cause-them) when applied to dates and times. It's better to use a word like "postpone" or to clear up the ambiguity explicitly (e.g., "...push back the appointment to Thursday").